# hive:varchar column could not return month

Tags: sql, date, hive

How to return month from `varchar` column and values like "20180912" in hive?

It's strange that it worked fine with function `month()` on string type in hive,however it returns null now.
And `month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp)(date,'yyyymmdd'))` return vaules that do not match the real month

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr()`:

```
hive> select substr('20180912',5,2);
OK
09
Time taken: 1.675 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```